# I am using kendo Grid and when I press Update I get this error:TypeError: r is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo UI to creat a grid in MVC.
this is the view:

```
        var model = kendo.data.Model.define({
            batch: true,
            id: "ID",
            fields: {
                "ID": { editable: false },
                "PID": { editable: false },
                "FullName": { type: "string" },
                "FName": { type: "string" },
                "LName": { type: "string" },
                "Type": { type: "string" },
                "Year": { type: "string" },
                "Viewed": { type: "number" }

            }
        });
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Asfa/Search",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST"
                },
                Update: {
                    url: "/Asfa/Update",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == 'success') {

                        }
                    }
                },

                                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },


            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                model: model,
                errors: "Error"
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.errors);
            }
        });


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            autoBind: true,
            scrollable: true,
            dataBinding: function () {
                record = (this.dataSource.page() - 1) * this.dataSource.pageSize();
            },
            navigatable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            reorderable: true,
            columnMenu: true,
            selectable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5,},

            toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
            height: 550,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Viewed",
                    template: "<label>نا مشخص<input disabled type='radio' value='#: Viewed #' #= Viewed== '0' ? 'checked' : ''# >" +
                              "<label>تایید شده<input disabled type='radio' value='#: Viewed #' #= Viewed== '1' ? 'checked' : ''# >" +
                              "<label>تایید نشده<input disabled type='radio' value='#: Viewed #' #= Viewed== '2' ? 'checked' : ''# >"
                    ,
                    editor: "<label>نا مشخص<input name='Viewed' type='radio' data-bind='checked:Viewed' value='0'>" +
                    "<label>تایید شده<input name='Viewed' type='radio' data-bind='checked:Viewed' value='1'>" +
                    "<label>تایید نشده<input name='Viewed' type='radio' data-bind='checked:Viewed' value='2'>"
                    ,
                    title: "وضعیت", width: "120px"
                },
                { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: "120px" },
                { field: "PID", title: "PID", width: "120px" },
                { field: "FullName", title: "FullName", width: "120px" },
                { field: "FName", title: "FName", width: "120px" },
                { field: "LName", title: "LName", width: "120px" }
                { field: "Type", title: "Type", width: "120px" },
                { field: "Year", title: "Year", width: "120px" },
            ],
            editable: true,
                Update: true,
            },
            //},

        });
    }
```

this is the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(FinalPerson obj)
    {
        using (var d = new AsfaEntities())
        {
            return Json(new { Data = UpdatePersons(obj) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(FinalPerson person)
    {
        using (var d = new AsfaEntities())
        {
            return Json(new { Data = d.FinalPersons.Where(x => x.ID > 229213 && x.ID < 230213 && x.Viewed == 0).ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    public FinalPerson UpdatePersons(FinalPerson obj)
    {
        using (var d = new AsfaEntities())
        {
            var dbObj = d.FinalPersons.Where(p => p.ID == obj.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            dbObj.FName = obj.FName;
            dbObj.FullName = obj.FullName;
            dbObj.LName = obj.LName;
            dbObj.PID = obj.PID;
            dbObj.Type = obj.Type;
            dbObj.Viewed = obj.Viewed;

            d.SaveChanges();

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

it works fine until I press save changes it doesn't update and this error appear:
TypeError: r is undefined
I searched but I don't understand the problem!

Comment: try adding `batch: true,` to `DataSource` object as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the updated object in your Update method of the controller.